# How to send email through SMTP to email address contain non-ASCII word

Tags: c#, .net, smtp, non-ascii-characters

How to send email through SMTP to email address which contain non-ASCII word.

Consider an users with email id : téést@test.com

Code is not throwing any exception and while checking the delivery report it gave an error message: 
"*Technical details of permanent failure:
 local-part of envelope RCPT address contains utf8 but remote server did not offer SMTPUTF8* ".

I am using .net 4.5 and my code sample is :

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
message.From="test@test.com";
message.Subject = "subject";
message.IsBodyHtml = true;
message.Body = "body";
message.To.Add("téést@test.com");

SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
smtp.Host = "SMTPServer";
smtp.Port = "SMTPPort";
var userName = "SMTPUserName";
var password = "SMTPPassword";
smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);
smtp.EnableSsl = true;
smtp.DeliveryFormat = SmtpDeliveryFormat.International;
smtp.Send(message);
```

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: The mail server must support Unicode addressing, the server you are sending to does not.